# How to prevent threading error in Xamarin Forms when using a control with a custom renderer in a secondary window?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

**The problem**:

I'm trying to open a new window in a Xamarin forms app on windows which contains custom `Entry` control.

When the new window is opened, a thread exception is thrown from the `Entry` control's custom renderer when trying to get the desired size.

The exception thrown is:
System.Exception: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

```
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.put_MinHeight(Double value)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.FormsTextBox.GetCopyOfSize(FormsTextBox control, Size constraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.EditorRenderer.GetDesiredSize(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.GetNativeSize(VisualElement element, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsBasePlatformServices.GetNativeSize(VisualElement view, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnSizeRequest(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint, MeasureFlags flags)
   at Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView.OnSizeRequest(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint, MeasureFlags flags)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.GridStructure.CalculateAutoCells(Grid grid, Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.GridStructure..ctor(Grid grid, Double width, Double height, Boolean requestSize)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.LayoutChildren(Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds(Rectangle value)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(VisualElement child, Rectangle region)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.LayoutChildren(Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Bounds(Rectangle value)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(VisualElement child, Rectangle region)
   at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedView.LayoutChildren(Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.ResolveLayoutChanges()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
```

**What I've tried**:

- Manually determining the size - it doesn't seem possible to do this in a robust way.
- Running the base `GetDesiredSize` method in the right thread - there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to run this and get the result. `MainThread` supports this but runs on the apps main UI thread not the window's.

**Some Code**:

Code to show new window:

```cs
        public async Task<T> ShowNewWindow<T>() where T : ContentView
        {
            var newViewId = 0;
            _coreDispatcher = CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher;

            ContentView contentView = null;

            await RunInUIAsync(async () =>
            {
                Type generic = typeof(T);
                contentView = (ContentView)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
                newViewId = view.Id;

                var frame = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame();
                var contentPage = new ContentPage() { Content = contentView };
                frame.Navigate(contentPage);
                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                Window.Current.Activate();

                bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId, ViewSizePreference.UseHalf, ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id, ViewSizePreference.UseHalf);
            });
            return (T)contentView;
        }
```

Calling code:

```cs
 ISecondaryWindowService secondaryWindowService = DependencyService.Get<ISecondaryWindowService>();
            if (secondaryWindowService != null)
            {
                  await secondaryWindowService.ShowNewWindow<CustomContentView>();
            }
```

CustomContentView:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ApplicationName.Controls">
    <controls:CustomEditor/>
</ContentView>
```

CustomEditor:

```cs
public class CustomEditor : Editor
{
}
```

Custom Renderer:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(CustomEditorRenderer))]
namespace ApplicationName.UWP.Controls
{
    public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: "a thread exception" is vague and unhelpful.  Please post the specific exception and details, and the code that generates it

Comment: Edited to include exception, full stack trace and some sample code.

Comment: Xamarin Forms isn’t designed to support a second window. Defer that until Maui is stable.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using maui check your `Windows Package.appxmanifest`.
For me it was a incorrect EntryPoint, the Application tag should be like this:

```
<Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
```

The issue disappears for me, I think WinUI is now starting the right exe (MAUI).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @DTynewydd Sure I edited my answer, please give me a feedback, I can help you. I am migrating Xamarin Forms to MAUI